# Should I override strings in other languages even if the text is the same as the default culture?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, localization, resharper, resx

We have a MVC website and our intention is to support a few languages out of the box. When translating a few strings on a resource file from English to Brazilian Portuguese, I noticed some warnings from Resharper, stating that some strings were not overridden in the pt-br file.

I followed it's proposed fix, and put them in the Portuguese resx, but them it started complaining that the translation is redundant and that I should remove the string.

There are a few field names or phrases that are the same across both languages, like `Email` for instance. What is the correct approach then? Should I override them in the specific language keeping the same text and suppress the "redundancy" warning, or should I place them only in the default resx and disable the "untranslated" warning?

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate rarely seems like a good option. In this case I'll choose the easiest way : if the ressources are the same across the languages I will keep them in the default resx. Then if a change is needed it will apply easily for every languages.